# Google Sheets add-on Sidebar click event does not work for some users

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, add-on

**Google Sheets add-on Sidebar issue**

On click of a menu item in the the sidebar, the app script function present in Code.gs does not trigger. `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler().withFailureHandler().generateContract();` ---> does not work for some users.

**Code.gs**

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createAddonMenu().addItem('Sidebar', 
  'showSidebar').addToUi();  
}

function generateContract() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.alert("Hello there! You're in the generateContract Function.");
  return;
}

function showSidebar() {  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Data");  
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var emailID = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
    var html= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('sidebar').setTitle("Sidebar");
  ui.showSidebar(html);
  
}
```

The alert **"Hello there! You're in the generateContract Function."** does not get fired for some users. Not sure why.

**sidebar.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">  
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
        function generatecontracts() {
            document.getElementById("generate-contracts").classList.toggle("show");
        }

        function GenerateContract() {
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler().withFailureHandler().generateContract();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0px; overflow: hidden">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <div class="d-flex">
            <button onclick=generatecontracts() class="dropbtn db-txt">
                Generate Contracts
            </button>
            <button onclick=generatecontracts() class="arrow">&#x25BC;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown-content" id="generate-contracts">
            <button class="drop-btn" onClick='GenerateContract()'>Generate Contract</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For troubleshooting you need to provide more code (both the content of `generateContract()` as well as the Javascript funciton where `google.script.run` is embedded. What is the difference between the users for which it works and for which it does not? How is the spreadsheet share? (view/edit access)? Also, if you go on `View-Executions` you should be able to see the exact error message which would help to understand why it `does not work `.

Comment: What si the content of `showSidebar()`? Can you implement logs to verify either it is being triggered? And also logs into `GenerateContract()` for the same reason? The behavior might be due to being signed in with multiple accounts. Ask the users with the problem to sign out of all accounts minus the one which has editor access to the sheet and / or try in incognito mode.

Comment: Open the browser's developer tools console log and look for any errors when the sidebar loads.  Sometimes there are uncaught errors when the sidebar loads.  To know whether the client side function is running, add a `console.log('It ran')` statement to the function, and when you click the button, you should see the message logged to the browsers developer tools console log.  If the client side code is not running, then there is something wrong with how the browser is evaluating the html when it loads.

Comment: Try double quotes

Comment: I tried to replicate your problem scenario with different browsers, google accounts, GAS V8/classic, etc... but everything works fine. Please, provide more information like console logs or execution transcripts.

Comment: Did you define `withSuccessHandler()` and `withFailureHandler()`? Implement some logs into them for troubleshooting, e.g.  `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).withFailureHandler(onFailure).generateContract();`  and 
 `function onFailure(error) {
console.log( error.message);}`